# How to redirect to a new page, when infopath form is submitted to the server in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath-2007

I'm using share point 2007.
Once i submit the info path form to the server, form is being closed and it's redirected to share point library [i have used the option - "After submit --> close the form"] . i have another library i.e. "view" of the database. i need to redirect the form to this "view" once form is submitted.
How to redirect to a page, when a form is being submitted to share point server ?
OR
How to close the browser window automatically when form is submitted ?